# Constructing Unix Mail With "In-Reply-To:"

Tags: shell, email, unix, sendmail, sh

I want to use the Unix "mail" command to send emails that include an "In-Reply-To:" header record.  Under some Linux versions it seems I can use "-a" to add arbitrary header records, but on some versions that doesn't seem to be available.  Also, I need to do this on AIX, where the "mail" command seems to have far fewer options than on Linux.  I'm running as a regular user (not root), and the SA's seem to have set up sendmail.

As some background -- I monitor several Unix servers via cron-fired shell scripts that run every ten minutes and send an email if conditions arise that need attention.  Sometimes several scripts on several servers are emailing at once, every ten minutes, and the number of emails is quite high.  The new mobile device I use to receive these emails can't group email by any attribute other than by "conversation," and so, to keep some sanity to that device's inbox I want to control the "In-Reply-To:" of these emails.

Comment: I think you can just pipe your message, with all the headers you want, into `sendmail`.

Answer (score 1):

### Sending Unix/Linux email with custom headers using sendmail

You may use sendmail directly to send emails and generate any email headers you want.  Sendmail will add missing *important* header (e.g. `Date:`, `From:`)

```
#!/bin/sh

RECIPIENT=john.doe@example.net

/usr/sbin/sendmail -i --  $RECIPIENT<<END_OF_MAIL
To: <$RECIPIENT>
Subject: Test Message
X-Custom-Header: WOW!

Body of the message line 1
Body of the message line 2
END_OF_MAIL
```

BTW Postfix, Exim and other Unix/Linux MTA programs provide "sendmail look alike" program for email sending.